# Css stack images while keeping tallest height

Tags: css

i'm trying to stack 3 images inside a container so they appear on top of each others.

My issue is i don't know the image size and i want my container to be equal to the tallest height. I also don't want to use javascript.

Here is a fiddle that demonstrate the expected result and is actually a solution to my problem but only works on Chrome !

http://jsfiddle.net/TnVVa/

here is the html part of it :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="firstImage.jpg"/>
    <img src="secondImage.jpg"/>
    <img src="thirdImage.jpg"/>
  </div>

  <div class="text">
    This is my text
  </div>
</div>
```

i'm looking to have the same result on other browsers (at least firefox and IE10+, if more thats better)

As a bonus it would awsome to have the 3 images be vertically centered in their container.

Comment: you may take a look at : http://www.thegridsystem.org/ CSS grid system is still on draft. as far as i know , only webkit and IE10 + ( http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/GridSystem/Default.html )as something close to it

Comment: @vivekvikranth how could i clarify it ? thanks

Comment: @GCyrillus thanks for the links, i read them, but did not found any hints on a suitable solution (interesting read tho). i'm not sure the css grid is the way to go but i used it in the fiddle to show the desired result.